# Events not logged in firebase console

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I just don't know what to do anymore. I have a React-Native app and I'm trying to use Firebase Analytics to log Events in the app. I'v followed the entire installation of https://rnfirebase.io/ and https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage. Having done that I'v tried to log an Event but I can't see it in Firebase.
What left me completely baffled is that activating the app for Debug View mode with -FIRDebugEnabled in XCode worked. I could send an Event on the app and see it on the Debug View console in Firebase. When I deactivated the Debug mode WITHOUT ANY CHANGE only -FIRDebugDisabled in XCode the app did not send any Events to the Events console. I don't get any error there is no way to know what is happening. I have no idea of what I need to do or how to fix it.
Maybe some configuration inside the GoogleServices-Info.plist? Something inside the Scheme in XCode?
What should I do?

EDIT: I´v read a lot of answers here. Just to clarify the Events names are not a problem (no spaces or more than 40 chars) and I´v filtered Today and all posibles filters.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the DebugView, Firebase doesn’t display data in real time. There’s an intended delay before the analytics data is logged on your Analytics dashboard. The initial data logged usually takes up to 24 hours to display and 3-4 hours delay for the succeeding data. For additional information about it, you can refer to this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html).